# Getting an exception as I try to run a query. Why is that?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

The following snippet throws an exception :

```
String hqlSelectDB = "use librarian";
sess.createQuery(hqlSelectDB).list();
```

*Exception*

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:31)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
servlets.InsertPerson.doPost(InsertPerson.java:41)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Why am I getting this exception ?

Answer (score 1):

`use librarian` is not a valid query and its not returning any result.

Try some valid query as `from librarian.SomeTable t`

If you have a look at [Hibernate Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-sessionfactory), you need to specify which DB you want to use, during configuration phase itself.

This is the example of hibernate configuration property file, which will be used by hibernate to make a `SessionFactory` (A kind of Connection pool), which will give the DB Connection.

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase --> This is where you specify your DB name
hibernate.connection.username = myuser
hibernate.connection.password = secret
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: How to select the database ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
String hqlSelectDB = "from librarian";// where librarian is data object mapped with DB table
sess.createQuery(hqlSelectDB).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Query you are going to use is not a `HQL` query

```
From librarian
```

will work